# Assign attribute to function

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributes

This is probably very much a beginner question, but I have a question about attributes. 
I have a module responsible for Google Docs API actions which contains functions for retrieving information. I would like to be able to refer to certain variables from these functions as attributes.
Here is an example:

Gdocs.py

```
def getRows():
    rows = #action for getting rows
    rowsText = #action for converting to text
```

General.py

```
import Gdocs
text = Gdocs.getRows.rowstext
```

I know the basic effect of passing variables can be achieved by just returning the values, but I would like to refer to them as attributes if possible. Simply put, my question is, how can you create an attribute of a function that I can reference in another .py document?

Thanks and sorry if it has been already answered, I did try to search but kept running nto very specific problems.

Comment: Attributes of *what* exactly?

Comment: You probably want a class, not just a function, if you have both attributes and methods.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I wanted to create an attribute of the function gerRows above

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I wanted to use a class as well but got tangled up in the way to do that. If my Gdocs.py has several classes, then I can refer to the attribute but it seemed to me like it wasn't normal to do a class for each function I need. Could somebody show me a basic example of how it could work so I can reference the variable something like: text = Gdocs.getRows.rowstext?

Comment: Function attributes are just namespaced globals; it is not clear what problem you are trying to solve here though.

Comment: Note that functions can easily return multiple values in a tuple.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I am not really trying to solve a problem so much as trying to make my code more understandable to myself as I am just a beginner. I had gotten used to referring to variables like funtion.name and I wanted to be able to do the same.

Comment: @user3107876: You are not making it any more understandable to either jonrsharpe or me though.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I'm sorry about confusing you guys. I could tell from the bad search results that what I wanted was going to be weird. Really what I wanted was to be able to retrieve the different variations of a result from a function without having to bring everything back in a tuple. Something like result.string, result.int, result.list etc..

Comment: @tudorleriu: sounds like you want a `namedtuple` then. Function attributes are basically globals; using attributes on the function object to return function results is *not* thread safe, for example.

Comment: Why not simply use a function argument to determine whether to return this or that? Like: `def getRows(astext=False): return rowsText if astext else rows`

Comment: I have to disagree with @MartijnPieters in this circumstance; seems more likely someone would want one or the other of "rows" and "rows converted to text" than both at once in a `namedtuple`... but it is certainly an odd question to try to interpret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if you want to return a result consisting of multiple parts. Don't use function attributes for this, return a *new* object that can be addressed via attributes instead. That'd make it thread-safe as well, as function attributes live in the same scope as the function object itself: as a global.

The standard library has a helpful class factory function for just such return values, [`collections.namedtuple()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')

def calculate_coordinates(foo, bar, baz):
    return Point(42, 81)
```

The return value is a tuple subclass, so it can be addressed like a tuple (with indexing), it can be unpacked into separate values, or you can use attributes:

```
result = calculate_coordinates(spam, ham, eggs)
print result.x, result.y
```

or

```
res_x, res_y = calculate_coordinates(spam, ham, eggs)
```

all work.

Answer (score 0):

While I understand what you said about not wanting a class for each function...

When you have a class, you can apply the @property decorator to functions. 
This has the effect of allowing you to effectively create functions that exhibit behaviors but can be called just like attributes. In the following, if you wanted to produce a list of squares based on the input list, you could create a function with a verb-like name called create_list_of_squares(). But in this case, if you really want to keep the API simple and abstract away the mechanics behind the method and simply enable users to access the attributes 'squares', you can use a property decorator, like this...

```
class SquareList(list):
    @property
    def squares(self):
        return [x ** 2 for x in self]

s = SquareList([1, 2, 3, 4])
print s.squares
```

which will yield:

```
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little weird, but you can use `staticmethod` and classes to get what you want.  To wit:

## source: zattr2.py

```
class getRows(object):
    @staticmethod
    def rows(arg):
        return [arg, arg]

    @staticmethod
    def rowsText(arg):
        return repr(arg)
```

## usage:

```
>>> import zattr2
>>> zattr2.getRows.rowsText('beer')
"'beer'"
```

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod